# Making JSON requests within Emacs

Tags: json, emacs, elisp, stackexchange-api

I am in the early stages of writing an [Emacs major mode](https://github.com/vermiculus/sx.el) for browsing and contributing to sites on the Stack Exchange network, in much the same way as `dired` and `list-packages` works, with a few inspirations from `magit` and `org-mode`.

The problem is, of course, I have *no idea* how I would interface Emacs with the SE API (v2.1) in the first place.  I've never done anything that involves a network connection within Elisp, although I'm comfortable with the language itself (and have taken more than a few looks at `package.el`).

I've never worked with JSON, although I'm in the middle of [W3C's tutorial](http://www.w3schools.com/json/default.asp) on it.

A simple 'hello world' would suffice, possibly along the lines of

```
(execute-json-query "/info")
```

The W3C tutorial doesn't seem to go over requests, either.  I'll have to do my own research on that.
I really don't have any idea what I'm doing; I've only just started feverishly working on this yesterday afternoon.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

The problem with other answers is that [Stack Exchange API is GZIP'd](http://api.stackoverflow.com/1.1/usage/gzip) and url.el shipped with Emacs does not automatically decompress it.

Take a look at my [request.el](http://tkf.github.io/emacs-request/) library which supports automatic decompression (to be honest, I just added the support).  Here is an example to fetch the most active question in stackoverflow:

```
(request
 "https://api.stackexchange.com/2.1/questions"
 :params '((order . "desc")
           (sort . "activity")
           (site . "stackoverflow"))
 :parser 'json-read
 :success (function*
           (lambda (&key data &allow-other-keys)
             (let* ((item (elt (assoc-default 'items data) 0))
                    (title (assoc-default 'title item))
                    (tags (assoc-default 'tags item)))
               (message "%s %S" title tags)))))
```

request.el is [well documented](http://tkf.github.io/emacs-request/manual.html), comes with [executable examples](http://tkf.github.io/emacs-request/#examples) and is [well tested](https://travis-ci.org/tkf/emacs-request).

Comment: This is awesome.  I actually looked at this package *while researching the package* but was lost for it.  Unfortunately, running your example as-is produces an error which I must host on https://gist.github.com/vermiculus/5050463.

Comment: As I mentioned, I just added the gzip support.  Check `request-version` and if it's not 0.2.0alpha1, you need to update it.

Comment: Also, you need curl if you need automatic decompression.

Comment: Doesn't melpa just refer to the blob in its package listings?  That's where I installed yours from.

Comment: It takes some time to be packaged by melpa.  Checkout https://twitter.com/melpa_emacs

Comment: This request.el library looks awesome.  Thanks tkf.

Comment: @tkf, I'm having a lot of trouble getting this set up.  Now it just won't connect, it seems.  Head on over to the [Emacs](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/25252/emacs) room I set up?  I feel like this doesn't belong in the comments.

Comment: Actually, I may jave just found the problem.  Hold on...  **Got it.**

Comment: @tkf, could you explain a bit more about what you are doing with `:success`?  I understand from the documentation that it specifies a function to be called upon success, but its use isn't terribly well-documented (but almost learn-by-example).  Is there some reason one has to specify `&allow-other-keys`?

Comment: The reason why you need `&allow-other-keys` is in the document http://tkf.github.com/emacs-request/manual.html#request.  If you don't know what `&allow-other-keys` does, read CL's document `M-: (info "(cl) Argument Lists") ERT`.

Comment: @tkf What if one just wanted to simply return the (parsed) object on success?

Comment: You mean you want blocking call?  You can use `:sync t` if you want.  See the manual for more info.

Comment: Ah! assoc-default was what I've been hunting down. Thanks for this answer

Comment: Does not seem to work on Windows. I get just `REQUEST [error] Error (error) while connecting to https://api.stackexchange.com/2.1/questions.`

Comment: Reqeust.el is a slick package, but if you're using authentication you have to fall back to uri.el

Answer (score 11):

Take a look at [REST Client on GitHub](https://github.com/pashky/restclient.el) - a tool to manually explore and test HTTP REST webservices.

Comment: This is really cool.  This might end up being the marked answer if there are no others, but *especially* if you provide an example of an elisp expression (using `restclient` if necessary) that will resolve to the returned string.

Answer (score 8):

This may not be the best way of doing things but it seems to work for me.

```lisp
(defun fetch-json (url)
   (with-current-buffer (url-retrieve-synchronously url)
     ; there's probably a better way of stripping the headers
     (search-forward "\n\n")
     (delete-region (point-min) (point))
     (buffer-string)))
```

Then calling this function with a url will return the content of the response, in this case, json.  I've used the reddit api as an example because I'm not sure how the Stack Exchange api works.

```lisp
 (fetch-json "http://reddit.com/r/emacs.json")
```

There is pretty much no error checking included here, if the url returns no data then this will blow up.

Comment: FWIW, the better way of stripping the headers is `(goto-char url-http-end-of-headers)`.