# JSON requests within Emacs, Phase 2: Getting a collection of items

Tags: json, request, elisp

I'm trying to get a list of sites (a list of a-lists) with the Stack Exchange API using [`request.el`](http://tkf.github.io/emacs-request/).

I'm making [an Emacs major mode for Stack Exchange](https://github.com/vermiculus/sx.el), so this has some nice potential payoff for you Emacs users out there. ;) (And since I tagged elisp, I'm assuming that's the lot of you.)

To do this, a fundamental necessity would be to make a request for JSON, and then view the list of returned sites.  The StackExchange API supplies the [/sites](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/sites) resource, and a request for that resource returns a collection of [site](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/types/site) objects like so:

```
{
  "items": [
    {
      "site_type": "main_site",
      "name": "Stack Overflow",
      "logo_url": "http://cdn.sstatic.net/stackoverflow/img/logo.png",
      "api_site_parameter": "stackoverflow",
      "site_url": "http://stackoverflow.com",
      "audience": "professional and enthusiast programmers",
      "icon_url": "http://cdn.sstatic.net/stackoverflow/img/apple-touch-icon.png",
      "aliases": [
        "http://www.stackoverflow.com"
      ],
      "site_state": "normal",
      "styling": {
        "link_color": "#0077CC",
        "tag_foreground_color": "#3E6D8E",
        "tag_background_color": "#E0EAF1"
      },
      "launch_date": 1221436800,
      "favicon_url": "http://cdn.sstatic.net/stackoverflow/img/favicon.ico",
      "related_sites": [
        {
          "name": "Stack Overflow Chat",
          "site_url": "http://chat.stackoverflow.com",
          "relation": "chat"
        }
      ],
      "markdown_extensions": [
        "Prettify"
      ],
      "high_resolution_icon_url": "http://cdn.sstatic.net/stackoverflow/img/apple-touch-icon@2.png"
    },
    {
      "site_type": "main_site",
      "name": "Server Fault",
      "logo_url": "http://cdn.sstatic.net/serverfault/img/logo.png",
      "api_site_parameter": "serverfault",
      "site_url": "http://serverfault.com",
      "audience": "professional system and network administrators",
      "icon_url": "http://cdn.sstatic.net/serverfault/img/apple-touch-icon.png",
      ...
    },
    {
      "site_type": "main_site",
      "name": "Super User",
      ...
    {
      "site_type": "main_site",
      "name": "Meta Stack Overflow",
      ...
    }
    ...
}
```

I'd like to minimize the number of calls I make to the API and retrieve them all and place them in a data structure in one go for me to be able to make sense of it later on.

I'm trying to adapt one of the lovely solutions I've found here, [Making JSON requests within Emacs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15118304), to fit what I need to do.  It uses the [request.el](http://tkf.github.io/emacs-request/) library, from tkf.

The example tkf gave me was able to take the most active question on a site and grab its `title` and `tags` properties using `json-read`, which essentially turns an object into an a-list.  This attempt is based off of that solution:

```
(request
 "https://api.stackexchange.com/2.1/sites"
 :parser 'buffer-string
 :success (function*
       (lambda (&key data &allow-other-keys)
         (let* ((items    (assoc-default 'items data))
            (names    (mapcar (lambda (item) (assoc-default 'name        item)) items))
            (launches (mapcar (lambda (item) (assoc-default 'launch-date item)) items)))
           (mapcar* (lambda (name launch)
              (message "name:`%s` launch:`%s`" name launch))
            names
            launches)))))
```

...but seems entirely ineffective.  The other examples work perfectly, so it is something wrong with my usage.

request.el can be downloaded from the MELPA package repository and, to my knowledge, requires `curl` to run correctly (which I have).

I suspect the problem lies in my usage (or preparation thereof) of `mapcar*`, where the following does work as expected:

```
(mapcar* (lambda (a b) (insert a) (insert b)) '(1 2 3) '(4 5 6))
```

I know this post is long, but I tried to provide as much information as I could.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were almost there.  This one works for me:

```
(request
 "https://api.stackexchange.com/2.1/sites"
 :parser 'json-read
 :success (function*
       (lambda (&key data &allow-other-keys)
         (let* ((items    (assoc-default 'items data))
            (names    (mapcar (lambda (item) (assoc-default 'name        item)) items))
            (launches (mapcar (lambda (item) (assoc-default 'launch_date item)) items)))
           (mapcar* (lambda (name launch)
              (message "name:`%s` launch:`%s`" name launch))
            names
            launches)))))
```

Two changes:  1. use `json-read` instead of `buffer-string` for parser argument.  2. use `launch_date` instead of `launch-date` as the key for alist.

Comment: Oh goodness, I'd forgotten that I'd changed the parser function.  Thanks again, @tkf!  One small question though: each time I execute a `request`, a message appears: "`[cl-struct-request-response nil nil nil nil nil "https://api.stackexchange.com/2.1/sites" nil (:parser json-read :success (lambda (&rest --cl-rest--) "

(fn &key DATA &allow-other-keys)" (let* ... ...)) :error (closure (t) (&rest args) (apply ... ... args)) :url "https://api.stackexchange.com/2.1/sites" :response #0) #<buffer  *request curl*> nil nil ...]`" -- am I doing something wrong, or is this normal?

Comment: If you are evaluating the expression using `C-x C-e` or `C-M-x` that's normal.  Emacs is just printing the returned value.