# How to hook emacs up to a json service?

Tags: json, asp.net-web-api, emacs, elisp

I don't know a lot about programming emacs, though i do know how to program in Lispy languages.  I have a service that watches a project directory and produce results through a rest-like web interface.  I'd like to hook emacs into this service and maybe use this kind of scheme to program some features for emacs.  I'm not really sure where to start on the emacs side.  So what libs would work best for hitting a web service?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15118304/making-json-requests-within-emacs.  The answer there mentions the [request](https://github.com/tkf/emacs-request) library, which I have not used.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Emacs has pretty good built-in support for this kind of thing, at least at the basic level of making requests and parsing responses.  Use `url-retrieve` or `url-retrieve-synchronously` to fetch data from a remote service.  As the names suggest, one is an asynchronous call which takes a callback, the other a blocking call which returns a buffer containing the response.  Load them by including `(require 'url)` in your Elisp file.

The `url-` functions are documented in a separate Info manual from the rest of Elisp, named "URL", but some useful features go unmentioned there.  For GET requests where arguments are passed in the URL, the `url-build-query-string` function is useful for constructing a string of query parameters from an a-list of keys and values.  For POST, PUT, DELETE and other requests, you may need to let-bind the variables `url-request-data`, `url-request-method` and `url-request-extra-headers`.  They have informative docstrings.

A final confusing thing about using these calls for HTTP URLs is that they leave the HTTP response headers in the same buffer as the response body, which may not be what you expect.  A simple way to deal with this is to use the (undocumented) `url-http-end-of-headers` variable to skip over the headers before processing the body, though I suspect there might be better ways.

Use the `json-read` function to parse JSON responses, and bind the variables `json-array-type`, `json-object-type`, and `json-key-type` to control how JSON types are converted to Lisp types.  This function is obtained by including `(require 'json)`.  XML responses can be parsed using `xml-parse-region` or `libxml-xml-parse-region`.  The latter requires Emacs to be compiled with libxml support, the former is implemented in Elisp.

Putting this together, the skeleton of a request to a JSON service looks something like this:

```
(url-retrieve
 "http://example.com/api/some/request"
 (lambda (events)
   (goto-char url-http-end-of-headers)
   (let ((json-object-type 'plist)
         (json-key-type 'symbol)
         (json-array-type 'vector))
     (let ((result (json-read)))
       ;; Do something with RESULT here
       ))))
```

In the callback, you can work with `result` like any other Lisp value. The `plist-get`, `pcase` and `cl-destructuring-bind` functions are often useful for extracting pieces of the result.  Use `(require 'pcase)` to get the `pcase` macro, `(require 'cl-lib)` to get `cl-destructuring-bind`.

Answer (score 3):

This is what I use to lookup currency exchange rates from a json webservice at rate-exchange.appspot.com:

```
(defun my-json-get (url)
  (interactive)
  (progn
    (require 'json)
    (with-current-buffer (url-retrieve-synchronously url)
      (goto-char (point-min))
      (re-search-forward "^$")
      (json-read))))
(defun my-currency-exchange-rate (from to)
  (let ((xurl (format "http://rate-exchange.appspot.com/currency?from=%s&to=%s" from to)))
    (assoc-default 'rate (my-json-get xurl))))
```

Example usage:

```
(my-currency-exchange-rate "USD" "SEK")
```